# How can I tell who is setting Cancel to true in OnClosing in C# WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form where I've got some code in the OnClosing to determine if I want to allow the form to close, as there are cases where I would cancel closing.

Trouble is, something, somewhere in my app is causing the CancelEventArgs.Cancel to be set to true, such that Cancel is true on the way into my OnClosing function. For the life of me, I cannot figure out where this is happening.

If I look at the call stack in OnClosing, there isn't anything except some external code and my Application.Run.

So the question is, how can I figure out who is setting Cancel = true?

Comment: Can you post some code..

Answer (score 2):

Are you saying that e.Cancel is true when you enter `OnClosing`  ?

One possible reason for this is if the forms `Validate` method fails, do you have any validation controls...

Take a look in reflector and you can see

```
private void WmClose(ref Message m)
{
  blah....
  e.Cancel = !base.Validate(true);
  blah....
```

Comment: Yup.  One workaround is to override OnFormClosing and force e.Cancel = false before calling the base method.

Comment: I COULD just set Cancel to false, but that's not fixing the problem. Let me check on validate......But yes you're correct, e.Cancel is true upon entering OnClosing.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your application in debug mode and put breakpoints in every Cancel = true statements.

The application will stop in the statement that is called and you can see where it is.